# How can I use RobotFramework to sudo in a ssh session where the sudo command doesn't require a password?

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, robotframework, sudo, paramiko

I trying to automate a program where I log into a ssh session with a username and password then I'm required to do a sudo su - "username" with no password. I'm able to log into the ssh session with out any problem but I am not able to get the sudo command to work. Looking at the Robot docs you should be able to put none for the password if there is no password but that just seems to cause the program to hang as if it's waiting for the password. The command I tried using is this.

```
Execute Command    su - "username"    sudo=True    sudo_password=None
```

I'm not sure if this is a bug with Robot Framework or it simply requires that password to work correctly.  I did write a interactive ssh using C where somebody could manually enter the sudo su command then the automation would continue. If anybody has any suggestions for the robot command, or how to possibly execute this using paramiko then I can import that library. Other thought I had was if I can get the C program to work with the robotframework then I can use that. Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a bug in Robot Framework. It's how the shell in Linux works and has nothing to do with the `sudo_password=None`.
I'm far from an expert explaining these stuff.
However, Robot Framework SSHLibrary use paramiko `exec_command` to execute the command.
And as described in the documentation, `Execute Command` will always be executed in a new shell that is then closed.
[SSHLibrary Doc - Execute Command](http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/SSHLibrary.html#Execute%20Command)

Let's try run this manually in the command line.
`ssh <login_user>@<server_ip> sudo su - <the_su_username>`
The command will not give any response and it hangs, just as it will do in Robot Framework and also Paramiko.

If we instead execute a command that will give a response it will work.
`ssh <login_user>@<server_ip> sudo ls -ltr`
This will work in robot framework as well if you try.
`Execute Command    ls -ltr    sudo=True    sudo_password=None`

As you say, it works if you use a interactive implementation in C.
I recommend you try implement using an interactive shell in Robot Framework as well.
That will run multiple commands in same shell.

You can find more details here how to use [Write](http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/SSHLibrary.html#Write) and [Read](http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/SSHLibrary.html#Read).

Comment: Ok so I was able to get the write command with sudo su actually to work and I'm thinking b/c i used the prompt and read until prompt. I'm able to get the file uploaded while staying on channel 1. Next step that I don't understand is why I can run "write cd ...." and change to the correct directory but then when I use the command "Write    ./somescript.sh"  and return the output it just returns the command and nothing seems to happen.

Comment: Does Write need a 2nd command after it. From the documentation it says it appends a newline which I would equate to hitting the return button after the .sh script. I did try adding \n and \r behind it but that only seems to add a black line and not execute anything. Any ideas.

Comment: You are right, there should be no need add newline for `Write` as default. I wonder if your script print the prompt character. In that case the `Read Until Prompt` would only read to that character and nothing after. You could try is to use read with a delay instead, a delay as long as expected script running. To see if you get expected output from the script. `${output}= Read delay=<your expected execution time for script> s`

Comment: For temporary debug you could also add a final print message in your script like `script execution successful`. And then user `Read Until    script execution successful` to make sure the script have executed successfully and that you get the expected output.